# Match {N,M} chars in Parboiled

Tags: scala, parboiled

How do I write a rule for

- at least N chars - regex [a-z](2,}
- at most N chars - regex [a-z](,5}
- from N to M chars - regex [a-z]{3,10}

in Parboiled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for the `times` combinator.  You can either use `times` with a single `Int` (meaning repeat the rule exactly `n` times) or with an `(Int, Int)` (meaning repeat the rule between `n` and `m` times).  You can use `times` together with `oneOrMore`, `zeroOrMore`, `~`, and `!` for the desired effects:

```
//Matches regex "a{n,}"
rule {
     n.times("a") ~ zeroOrMore("a") //match on n "a"s followed by zero or more "a"s (so at least n "a"s)
}

//Matches regex "a{,m}"
rule {
    !(m.times("a") ~ oneOrMore("a")) //do not match on m "a"s followed by one or more "a" (so at most m "a"s)
}

//Matches regex "a{n, m)"
rule {
     (n to m).times("a") ~ EOI
}
```

Comment: Please note, if you wan't to gain more performance (n <= 4) you can unroll the times rule. [The reason is described here](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2/issues/101)